# Find smallest divisor of string concatenations in python

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in two strings, I'm trying to check whether one is divisible by the other, one string  can be extended an arbitrary number of times to match the other string in its length, if this occurs than I need to return the smallest number of concatenations that take in order for one string to be divisible by the other:

This is my attempt:

```
def findSmallestDivisor(s, t):
    s_count = len(s)
    t_count = len(t)
    if s_count % t_count ==0:
        return t_count
```

let's say if s = `bcdbcdbcdbcd` and t = `bcdbcd` then it takes two concatentations of the unique string `bcd` from `t` to be divisible by `s`.

I would like to return the lenght of the unique set in case it's divisible which in the example above is `3`

Adding more examples as requested:

Let's say string s = `lrbblrbb` and string t=`lrbb` then if I double string `t` it will be divisible by string `s` and since string `t` has lenght `4` this should be the answer, however in the example I mentioned above the tricky part is when s = `bcdbcdbcdbcd` and t = `bcdbcd`. The answer should be `3` and not `6`, because `bcd` is the unique set and the other `bcd` in `t` is just a repetition.

Comment: Why in the example above it's 3? `t` fits inside `s` two times...

Comment: 3 is the length of the unique set `bcd` which the string is composed of

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think it is not very clear... Maybe some more examples of different scenarios would help clarify

Comment: Do you are actually looking for a solution to find the string `bcd` being the result? Because with your current function, you only deal with strings' length and I do not see how you could come to the result like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with simple pattern detection and string extension.

##### code

```py
def extend(s, t):
    """
    Extend t and check with s.
    """
    ret = None
    newt = t

    while True:
        newt = newt + t
        if len(s) % len(newt) == 0:
            ret = newt
            break

        if len(newt) > len(s):
            ret = None
            break

    return ret


def pattern(t):
    """
    Pattern detection by 2, (limited edition).
    Split t into 2 and compare, if the same then they are just doubled.
    If not then it is already unique.
    """
    ret = None
    t_count = len(t)

    if t_count >= 2:
        t1 = t[0:t_count//2]
        t2 = t[t_count//2:]

        # If the same then 1 part is the pattern.        
        if t1 == t2:
            ret = len(t1)
        # If not then the whole t itself is the pattern.
        else:
            ret = len(t)
    # Else if string length is less than 2 then just return 1 assuming t is not empty
    else:
        ret = 1  # unique

    return ret


def findSmallestDivisor(s, t):
    ret = None
    s_count = len(s)
    t_count = len(t)

    # Check if existing length of s is already divisible by existing length t
    if s_count % t_count == 0:
        ret = pattern(t)

    # Else if not divisible then we will extend t.
    else:
        newt = extend(s, t)
        if newt is not None:
            ret = pattern(t)

    return ret


def findSmallestDivisor(s, t):
    ret = None
    s_count = len(s)
    t_count = len(t)

    # Check if existing length of s is already divisible by existing length t.
    if s_count % t_count == 0:
        ret = pattern(t)

    # Else if not divisible then we will extend t.
    else:
        newt = extend(s, t)
        if newt is not None:
            ret = pattern(t)

    return ret


tests = {
    1: {
        's': 'bcdbcdbcdbcd',
        't': 'bcdbcd'
    },
    2: {
        's': 'lrbblrbb',
        't': 'lrbb'
    },
    3: {
        's': 'lrbblrbb',
        't': 'lrb'
    }
}


# Tests
data = []
for k, v in tests.items():
    s = v['s']
    t = v['t']
    data.append({'testnum': k, 's': s, 't': t, 'res': findSmallestDivisor(s, t)})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string())
```

##### Output

```
   testnum             s       t  res
0        1  bcdbcdbcdbcd  bcdbcd  3.0
1        2      lrbblrbb    lrbb  4.0
2        3      lrbblrbb     lrb  NaN
```